# Исключение при запуске javaFX приложения (версия 12.0.1)

Tags: java, javafx, модули

Разбираюсь с модулями в 12-ой джаве, написал пару вьюшек, просто хочу отобразить их, при запуске выдает исключение, ссылаясь в основном на `java.base` и `javafx.graphics`, что я не понял с подключением модулей?

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class zherikhov.App
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class zherikhov.App (in module java) because module java does not export zherikhov to module javafx.graphics
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:355)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:639)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

Приложу основной класс и класс-модуль

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {
    private Stage menuBar;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.menuBar = primaryStage;

        initMenuWindow();
        initMainWindow();
    }

    private void initMainWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("/fxml/mainWindow.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = loader.load();

            mainWindow.setCenter(personOverview);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initMenuWindow() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(App.class.getResource("/fxml/menuWindow.fxml"));
            mainWindow = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
            menuBar.setScene(scene);

            menuBar.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
module java {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: допишите в `module-info.java`

    opens zherikhov to javafx.fxml;
    exports zherikhov;

Comment: @zolt здорово, я гляну как именно это работает, но вот такой вопрос, а мне надо как-то указывать где у меня находятся fxml файлы? просто в 8ой версии этот же код работал, в классе App файлы вызываю правильно

Comment: @zolt спрашиваю, т.к. идет исключение на строку `mainWindow = loader.load();` в методе `initMenuWindow`

Comment: Специально нигде не надо указывать. Я делаю так: в папке `resource` путь до fxml основных совпадает с classpath исходников. Т.е. если у Вас в папке src путь до исходников выглядит как `zherikhov`, то и в папке `resource` создавайте паку `zherikhov` и кладите свои fxml туда. Таким образом до них можно будет дотянуться так `Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load("mainWindow.fxml");`

Comment: @zolt вы вроде как пишите элементарные вещи, но я что-то не пойму, мой путь к классу App идет след. образом - main/java/zherikhov, т.е. я должен создать такую структуру и в папке resources, и положить туда файлы fxml, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @zolt там выше скрин прикрепил

Comment: `main/java` не входят в `classpath`, т.е. у Вас нет например класса, полный путь до которого в `classpath` выглядит как `main.java.zherikhov.App`, есть класс с полным наименованием `zherikhov.App`, соответственно не нужно в `resources` добавлять `main/java`, достаточно добавить папку `zherikhov` и сложить туда Ваши fxml файлы. В итоге, в собранном виде полный путь в `classpath` до класса App будет `zherikhov.App`, а до `mainWindow.fxml` - `zherikhov/mainWindow.fxml`. Таким образом Вы сможете получить fxml в классе App просто по имени, т.к. файлы/классы в `classpath` буду на одном уровне.

Comment: @zolt ну значит я все правильно понял, но код почему-то не запускается, но это уже я думаю выходит за рамки данного вопроса, на изначальный вы ответили, я бы поставил правильный ответ, если  Вы его перенесете из комментариев, Вам спасибо